# A suspected bug in vcpkg curl on windows

Tags: c++, windows, curl, cmake, vcpkg

Simply doing: 
`vcpkg.exe install curl:x86-windows`

And then building with cmake:
`cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`

Would output:

```
C:\Users\altffour\Desktop\Projects\ContractNotifier\build>cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.17763.
CMake Error at C:/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/share/curl/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:5 (_find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "CURL" that is compatible
  with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/share/curl/CURLConfig.cmake, version: 7.66.0-DEV (32bit)
```

CMakeLists:

```
# curl
find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB_RECURSE hdrs "src/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE srcs "src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE ui "src/*.ui")
include_directories("." "src/")

add_executable(contractNotifier ${ui} ${hdrs} ${srcs})
target_link_libraries(contractNotifier Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Boost::serialization ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} CURL::libcurl)
```

Have I found a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved here https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/9290

Reason: Compiling all required packages with :x64-windows argument passed to vcpkg AND calling cmake with -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows compiles successfully!

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out that I was accidently compiling for x86 (which is default sometimes in CLion). Changing to x64 fixed the issue.